# Firebase storage and angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

How do to get the images from Fire base storage using angular fire 2. Thanks a lot!

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
this.items = af.database.list('/message');
this.picture = af.database.list('/profile');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Right now there isn't an official integration with AngularFire2 and Firebase Storage. However, it's quite easy to use the regular SDK.

```
@Component({

})
class MyComponent {
  image: string;
  constructor() {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('path/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
}
```

Then in your template

```
<img [src]="image" />
```

Comment: Hello, I can't just import the firebase like " import * as firebase from 'firebase'; " its giving me an error like cannot find the module. Thanks!

Comment: See [this}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310842/how-to-get-access-to-native-firebase-object-when-using-angularfire2) question for how to get the firebase object

Comment: using the declaration giving there, it works, but it still giving me an error that storageRef.getDownloadUrl is not a function. why is that? Thanks a lot! I really want to understand why is that happening.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo on my end, it's actually `getDownloadURL` not `getDownloadUrl`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This really works but I want to get all of the images. I'm trying to iterate on the path like ('profile/' + counter + '.jpg'); But i think it is not the right way? Thanks!

Comment: Does this still work? I'm trying to use an image in ionic2 but its not working until a page change happens. 99% its because there is no 2 way binding.

Comment: if i have a folder name 'folder' for example and including 3 images how can i get all the images in one call ? regards

Comment: while(this.i<=3){
      const storageRef  = firebase.storage().ref().child('home-slider-images/slide' + this.i + '.jpg');
      storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.images.push(url));
      this.i = this.i + 1;
    }
i'm doing this but i don't this it's right

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using AngularFire2, it is a good idea to access firebaseApp (firebase instance) inside AngularFire2 module. Here is the original [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067832/accessing-firebase-storage-with-angularfire2-angular2-rc-5).

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  template: '<p>testing</p>'
})
export class AnyComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: any) {
    const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('images/image.png');
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => this.image = url);
  }
}
```

Comment: if i have a folder name 'folder' for example and including 3 images how can i get all the images in one call ? regards