# Angular2Fire Access image in storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am using firebase with angular2 .I tired to access image in storage bucket of firebase with direct url of the image. It gave some security error but the same image can be viewed directly in the browser when entered in the address bar.

```
<img src="gs://img url in firebase storage">
```

It gives the following error
[image]

Then I tried the method by following the link [Angular2Fire Image access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593188/firebase-storage-and-angularfire2). But it returns me the object instead of url access.

TS:

```
recommendedListBind(list){
list.forEach(lists => {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(lists.thumbnail);
    let thumbnail = storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => url);

    let Detail = {
      title : lists.title,
      thumbnail : thumbnail,
    }

    this.recommendedList.push(Detail);
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let List of recommendedList">
    <div class='cards'>
        <img src={{List.thumbnail}} alt={{List.title}} title={{List.title}} />
  </li>
</ul>
```

It gives the following message:
[image]

What is the correct approach for accessing image in firebase storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Firebase Storage api either implement authentication or you can use the download url which doesn't require authentication and is based on a token which can be revoked in the console.

You can find more about authentication on [The Google Firebase Storage Security Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) and on the [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) github

Comment: Am not using authentication, and storage is open to read for all

Comment: if i revoke means I cant use the image know? will And using download image url be a security threat since storage is open to all for read?

Comment: 1. Revoking
  Revoking blocks that (and only that) download url from working. you can create a new one from the button under it (create download url).
 2. Download url
     The download url is a file specific url that gives anyone with that link access to the file no matter what authorization you have.
 3. Security parameters
     For a more secure system I would suggest creating an authentication flow and access files through there. You can set rules in the authentication flow using JSON or through the [BOLT compiler](https://github.com/firebase/bolt)