# AngularFire and Firebase - possible to use both?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm using Ionic2 with firebase. I have seen two ways to initialize firebase in app.ts
What is the preferred way of doing it and how to use both the functions? When I initialized in ionicBootstrap(), I'm loosing firebase functions and when I do it in the constructor, I'm loosing angularfire functions.

To use angularfire functions, it is initialized in ionicBootstrap

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [
    FIREBASE_PROVIDERS,
    // Initialize Firebase app  
    defaultFirebase({
        apiKey: "XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXX.appspot.com"
    }),
    provide('AppStore', { useValue: appStore }) ])
```

To use firebase functions, it is initialized in the constructor

```
constructor(private platform:Platform) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        StatusBar.styleDefault();

        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX",
            authDomain: "XXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "XXXXXX.appspot.com"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

    });
}
```

I have tried to move defaultFirebase() for angularfire2 in the constructor but it didn't work out. I'm getting this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Token FirebaseUrl! (AngularFire ->
>   Token FirebaseUrl)

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this approach too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39870804/1757321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution with this SO question/answer.

[How to get access to native Firebase object when using angularfire2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310842/how-to-get-access-to-native-firebase-object-when-using-angularfire2)

I'm using ionicBootstrap() to initialize firebase and replacing

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

by

```
declare var firebase : any;
```