# How to use firebase3 with angular2 without angularfire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've been using the angular2 quickstart code to build a basic todo app.

I was looking to add a login page and connection to firebase to store and retrieve the todo's but have had problems with the firebase3 implementation.

I can get it to work by removing the call to **tsc** in the starting script(shown below), but this seems like a short term fix.

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

The error i get when i run **npm start** says it cant find the name firebase for any of the times i use it in my component.tsc files. I also notice i haven't been able to find a firebase 3 global typing download yet so only have firebase 2 typings.

Could the difference in how firebase 2 and 3 are laid out (with firebase 3 being solely in the index.html and firebase 2 seemingly being declared throughout) be causing the problem???

Note my firebase experience is very limited so i could be misreading the difference between fb2 and fb3.

below is the error i currently get on **npm start**

```
> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/ahiggins/Documents/angular_2/tutorials/todo
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 

app/login/login.component.ts(25,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.
app/login/login.component.ts(47,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.
app/login/login.component.ts(56,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.
app/login/login.component.ts(59,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.
app/app.component.ts(16,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.4.0/bin/node" "/Users/ahiggins/.npm-packages/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310842/how-to-get-access-to-native-firebase-object-when-using-angularfire2

Comment: Look into this approach, which doesn't rule out AngularFire2 entirely from the equation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39870804/1757321