# Delete Firebase Users with Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Ionic2/Angular2, and have been looking for an example of how to delete users from Firebase.

If anyone has any examples, please can you help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two options for you:

**Drop down to the native Firebase SDK**

As in, you can follow the steps in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39870804/1757321) to acquire the current user, and remove it.

That will allow you do something along the lines of this, [from the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user):

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

**Try this snippet**

Using AngularFire2, [how about this approach](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/340#issuecomment-264659878)?

```
    af.auth
      .first()
      .subscribe(authState => {
        console.log(authState);
        authState.auth.delete()
          .then(_ => console.log('deleted!'))
          .catch(e => console.error(e))
      });
```

Don't forget the `.first()`

Comment: Thanks, I am using AngularFire2, so will go with that. Working for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The delete works like a charm :)
But how about the open subscriptions that I have for that user I deleted?
I'me getting "permission_denied" on all open subscriptions :(